# cassandra write performance issues. (5ms - 80ms)

Tags: cassandra

When saving data to cassandra, the performance of 70% of save takes around 4-8 ms. But 30% of the requests take around 80-90 ms. So trying to figure out why some of the requests are taking long. My suspect is it might be going across data center for these requests, but cant confirm it.

Also when using astyanax, we are pinning to the localhost, which will help to connect to the local cassandra coordinator. The primary key used here is a generated UUID.

I would really appreciate if some one can help with this issue.

```
Write Consistency: CL_ONE
Read Consistency: CL_LOCAL_QUORUM

using Astyanax for java client: 1.56.37
Cassandra version: 1.2.5
```

Heres the keyspace info:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE grd WITH replication = {
  'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
  'HYWRCA02': '2',
  'CHRLNCUN': '2'
};

CREATE TABLE route (
  routeid uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  allowdynamicstickyness boolean,
  businesskey uuid,
  createdby text,
  createdtimestamp timestamp,
  datapartitionkeyselectorref text,
  deletedby text,
  deletedtimestamp timestamp,
  envcontext text,
  lockedbyuser text,
  partner text,
  routelocationlatitudeselector double,
  routelocationlongitudeselector double,
  routelocationmaxdistanceselector double,
  routename text,
  sequence int,
  serviceidentifier text,
  stalenessinmins int,
  status text,
  stickykeyselector text,
  tags set<text>,
  type text,
  updatedby text,
  updatedtimestamp timestamp,
  versionmapnameref text,
  versionselector text
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='ALL' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  compaction={'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to login to one of the nodes of your cluster and execute cqlsh and choose your keyspace using USE:

```
[root@yournode ~]# cqlsh
Connected to YourCluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 3.1.2 | Cassandra 1.2.6 | CQL spec 3.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.36.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> use yourkeyspacehere ;
```

After this execute a tracing on command on cqlsh:

```
cqlsh:yourkeyspacehere> tracing on
Now tracing requests.
```

And then try running different queries on your table with different keys and check the times and IPs of the nodes involved in the query to check if there is an inter-datacenter connection. A sample output might look like this:

```
select * from your_table_name_is_here limit 1;

Tracing session: 1ab19ff0-2fa3-11e3-a9aa-2face31554b7

 activity                                                                                        | timestamp    | source         | source_elapsed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------
                                                                              execute_cql3_query | 22:52:12,528 | XXX.XX.XXX.XXX |              0
                                          Parsing select * from your_table_name_is_here limit 1; | 22:52:12,529 | XXX.XX.XXX.XXX |           1108
                                                                              Peparing statement | 22:52:12,530 | XXX.XX.XXX.XXX |           1555
                                                                   Determining replicas to query | 22:52:12,530 | XXX.XX.XXX.XXX |           1643
                                                           Message received from /XXX.XX.XXX.XXX | 22:52:12,534 | YYY.YY.YYY.YYY |             34
                                                            Enqueuing request to /YYY.YY.YYY.YYY | 22:52:12,536 | XXX.XX.XXX.XXX |           7549
                                                              Sending message to /YYY.YY.YYY.YYY | 22:52:12,536 | XXX.XX.XXX.XXX |           7812
 Executing seq scan across 9 sstables for [min(-9223372036854775808), max(-8721075978151533877)] | 22:52:12,538 | YYY.YY.YYY.YYY |           3609
                                                                    Scanned 1 rows and matched 1 | 22:52:12,550 | YYY.YY.YYY.YYY |          15977
                                                           Enqueuing response to /XXX.XX.XXX.XXX | 22:52:12,550 | YYY.YY.YYY.YYY |          16035
                                                              Sending message to /XXX.XX.XXX.XXX | 22:52:12,550 | YYY.YY.YYY.YYY |          16202
                                                           Message received from /YYY.YY.YYY.YYY | 22:52:12,557 | XXX.XX.XXX.XXX |          28494
                                                        Processing response from /YYY.YY.YYY.YYY | 22:52:12,557 | XXX.XX.XXX.XXX |          28647
                                                                                Request complete | 22:52:12,556 | XXX.XX.XXX.XXX |          28884
```

Hope it helps!